# jenkinsci / docker - installed libraries do not persist in rebuilds

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am using [jenkinssci/docker](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md) to setup some build automation on a server for a laravel project.

Using the command `docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts`, everything boots up fine, i create the admin login, create the project and link all of that together.

Yesterday i downloaded libraries to the container that this command gave me in docker using `docker exec -u 0 -it <container_name_or_id> /bin/bash` to get into the container as root to install things like php, composer, noodejs/npm. After this was done, i built the project and got a successful build.

Today I start the docker container using the same above command, build the project and build fails. The container no longer has any of the downloaded libraries (php, composer, node).

It is my understanding that including `jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home` in the command to start the docker container, data would persist. This is wrong?

So my question is, how can i make it so that i can keep these libraries in the docker container that it builds?

I just started learning about these tools yesterday, so i'm not entirely sure I am even doing it the best. All i need is to be able to log into the server for Jenkins and build the project/ship the code to our staging/live servers.

side note: I am not currently using a Dockerfile. [as mentioned here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md#installing-more-tools) I am able to download tools in the container as root.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct: you should use a persistent volume, otherwise you will lose your data every time the container is recreated.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are running the container in a single machine with docker. You need to put a full path or relative path on the local folder of the volume definition to be sure that data persists, try with:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v ./jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

Look at the `./` on the local folder

Here my docker-compose.yml I'm using for a long time

```
version: '2'
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    volumes:
      - ./jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
    ports:
      - 80:8080
      - 50000:50000
```

Is basically the same but in yaml format

Comment: i get this error `docker: Error response from daemon: create ./jenkins_home: "./jenkins_home" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.`

edit: is there an easy way for me to do it the way you are doing it, putting this into a file somewhere?

Comment: Be sure to create the folder before launching the container, Docker doesn't create it for you.